# Is there a way to force client resolve instead of DNS in Bind

Tags: dns, bind

I am using bind as a public resolver for a domain which returns different IP address based on the viewer's location (using maxmind's db). Problem is that client queries are not from the actual user IP but the address of the DNS server they use. I know this is a normal behaviour, but with the grow usage of public services like 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 we do get a lot of inaccurate data, e.g.:

user from Netherlands is resolved as a client from France
user from Bulgaria is resolved as a client from Germany

My question is - is there a configuration in bind which can force the client to be always the actual user who initiated the DNS resolve? Just like when you use `dig +trace`.

Comment: It might be worth checking to see if https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-ip-01.html was ever accepted into the protocol

Comment: [Ahem!](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/nitty-gritty-details/)

Comment: @roaima Indeed, it is RFC7871 "Client Subnet in DNS Queries". However not all recursive nameservers implement it.

Comment: Thank you all. I found that bind supports it only in subscribers edition and not in free.